# use incrontab to run a cron job when anything under a directory is modified using *

Tags: incrontab

how can I tell incrontab to run this command when there has been any modification done under the `/web` directory?

`/web IN_CREATE,IN_DELETE,IN_MODIFY /bin/echo "this is a test..."`

Comment: Just a hint: `/bin/echo` will not be connected to any terminal so the output goes nowhere (but you will get a info line that the action ran in the syslog).

Comment: +1 Your syntax looks right. Is it that you just don't see "this is a test..." displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the incrontab record syntax taken from [this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/):

```
<directory> <file change mask> <command or action>  options
```

So, your command should be OK. You need to pay attention to two points:

1. Add the needed changes in the record such as the mentioned in your question (IN_CREATE, etc...).
2. This record will watch only the directory the files/folders under it, but not under its subfolders. It is **NOT recursive**. You need to include more records if you want to watch other subfolders.